# Letting the Parent call the original Method instead of the overwritten one

Tags: ruby, oop

Given two Classes

```
class A
  def method_a ()
    method_b()
  end

  def method_b ()
    puts "Comes from A"
  end
end
```

and `B` inheriting from `A`

```
class B < A
  def method_a ()
    super()
  end

  def method_b ()
    puts "Comes from B"
  end
end
```

When i call `B.method_a` the Outcome would be: `Comes from B`. Is there a possibility to tell `A` to call its `method_b` instead of my overwritten one? (So that the result would be `Comes from A`)

Comment: Why did you override `method_b` when you don't plan to use it? What's your use-case?

Comment: Maybe this could work? `B.new.superclass.method_b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent of C++'s `A::method_a`

You could however do

```
class A
  def method_a
    A.instance_method(:method_b).bind(self).call
  end

  def method_b
    puts "Comes from A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def method_a
    super
  end

  def method_b
    puts "Comes from B"
  end
end
```

What is happening here in `method_a` is that we're retrieving A's implementation of `method_b` and calling it directly.

This does somewhat fly in the face of using inheritance in the first place though

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was searching for. Nonetheless I now see how its against the Inheritance Principle and I'm glad that i don't need to use this anymore because i found a flaw in my design

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it straight forward, without putting a hack, but wouldn't it defeat the purpose of `inheritance` and `template pattern`, as there can be a `C` class as well inheriting from `A`, and you may want to call `method_b` function of class `C` only, as it has been over-written and required.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not supported, since it defeats the point of inheritance. What you can do, is split the implementation into two methods - one that does `A`s implementation of `method_b`, which is not overridden, and one that *delegates* to that implementation, which may be overridden:

```
class A
  def method_a
    dont_override_me
  end

  def method_b
    dont_override_me
  end

  private
  def dont_override_me
    puts "Comes from A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def method_a 
    super
  end

  def method_b
    puts "Comes from B"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
  def method_a; comes_from_A end
  def method_b; puts "Comes from A" end
  alias comes_from_A method_b
end

class B < A
  def method_a; super end
  def method_b; puts "Comes from B" end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the child class as follows:

```
class B < A
  def method_a
    self.class.send(:remove_method, :method_b)
    super()
    self.class.send(:alias_method, :method_b, :method_b_alias)
  end

  def method_b
    puts "Comes from B"
  end

  alias_method :method_b_alias, :method_b
end

b = B.new

b.method_b
  # Comes from B
b.method_a
  # Comes from A
b.method_b
  # Comes from B
```

The alias `:method_b_alias` is created when the child class is created.  Whenever `method_a` is called on an instance of of `B`, `B`'s method `method_b` is removed before `super` is invoked, so `A`'s `method_a` will not find it and use its own `method_a` instead (since the receiver of `A`'s `method_a` (`self`) is the instance of `B`.)  After `super` returns, `alias_method` is used to once again make `B`'s `method_a` available to instances of `B`.

We need to use [Module#remove_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-remove_method) rather than [Module#undef_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-undef_method).  If the latter were used, `A`'s `method_a` would give up looking for `method_b` after finding that `B` did not have that method.

If you prefer, you could change two lines to use the keyword `alias` rather than `alias_method`:

```
self.class.send(:alias :method_b :method_b_alias)
alias :method_b_alias :method_b
```